# openssl cms not finding signer certificate

Tags: openssl

So I created a PKCS7 signed message and am trying to validate it with OpenSSL with the following command:

```
openssl cms -in demo.p7m -inform DER -verify
```

Doing so returns me the following error:

```
140653850015376:error 2E09D08A:CMS routines:CMS_verify:signer certificate not found:cms_smime.c:353:
```

I don't understand this error. Here's the output of `openssl asn1parse -in demo.p7m -i -inform DER`:

http://pastebin.com/AgkVbQjS

Here's the base64 encoded PKCS7:

http://pastebin.com/92mMPVw6

The X509 cert is as follows:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The cert parses just fine with `openssl x509 -in cert.txt -text -noout`.

The cert is a self-signed cert. The issuer DN is as follows:

```
   92:d=6  hl=2 l=  57 cons:       SEQUENCE          
   94:d=7  hl=2 l=  28 cons:        SET               
   96:d=8  hl=2 l=  26 cons:         SEQUENCE          
   98:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :organizationName
  103:d=9  hl=2 l=  19 prim:          UTF8STRING        :phpseclib demo cert
  124:d=7  hl=2 l=  25 cons:        SET               
  126:d=8  hl=2 l=  23 cons:         SEQUENCE          
  128:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :commonName
  133:d=9  hl=2 l=  16 prim:          UTF8STRING        :www.whatever.com
```

That matches the issuer DN in the SignerInfo:

```
  782:d=14 hl=2 l=  57 cons:               SEQUENCE          
  784:d=15 hl=2 l=  28 cons:                SET               
  786:d=16 hl=2 l=  26 cons:                 SEQUENCE          
  788:d=17 hl=2 l=   3 prim:                  OBJECT            :organizationName
  793:d=17 hl=2 l=  19 prim:                  UTF8STRING        :phpseclib demo cert
  814:d=15 hl=2 l=  25 cons:                SET               
  816:d=16 hl=2 l=  23 cons:                 SEQUENCE          
  818:d=17 hl=2 l=   3 prim:                  OBJECT            :commonName
  823:d=17 hl=2 l=  16 prim:                  UTF8STRING        :www.whatever.com
```

Here's the serial number of the SignerInfo:

```
  841:d=12 hl=2 l=   1 prim:             INTEGER           :00
```

This matches the serial number of the of the X509 cert:

```
   77:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim:       INTEGER           :00
```

So why isn't it finding the signing cert?

Answer (score 0):

I generated my own self-signed cert to test this, but I didn't get the same error.  Comparing the ASN.1 structures of my working PKCS#7 object and your non-working one, the differences I saw were:

- Your signing certificate expired on 2013-06-04
- The signed attributes of your PKCS#7 object contained an `id-aa-signingCertificateV2` attribute, which mine did not.
- The signed attributes of my PKCS#7 object contained `signingTime` and `S/MIME Capabilities` attributes, which yours did not.

My best guess is the expired cert was disregarded when looking for signer certificates, leading to the error.

Answer (score -3):

What you don't understand in the "can not find signer certificate" message? Your signed message does not contain a certificate.

Or, perhaps, you don't understand, what "cms -verify" command do. It does not veryfy the message integrity, it verifies the authenticity, and for that, it needs a certificate.

Comment: You are incorrect. The certificate starts at offset 64 and has an length of 487+4 per `asn1parse`'s output, as shown in http://pastebin.com/AgkVbQjS. The issuer DN of the cert (and subject DN for that matter since it's self-signed) that is included in the PKCS7 message matches the issuer DN in the SignerInfo. I explained all of this in my OP. SignerInfo does not include the certificate per the CMS / PKCS7 RFC. Do you want me to add the actual ASN.1 definition of CMS to my post? That said, serverfault.com is not a good venue for this question and I disagree with the questions migration.